# jquery autocomplete from local text file not picking up

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have tried following code picked from plunker to reduce ajax request to database. JSON format is also generated fine as per example in text file.

But when i'am trying to populate autocomplete options it's showing only one character of beginning. But when i use json output directly with items variable then it works fine.

**Plunker**
[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPoLCMjOnZhGq8qBe3I1?p=preview)

**JSON example in Keywords.txt file**

```
["Mis","Operation","Operation Manager","Php","Sales","Telecalling","Analytics","Ceo","Commercials"];
```

**Code**

```
$(function() 
{
    var items = 'Keywords.txt';         

    function split( val ) 
    {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) 
    {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#keyword" )
    .autocomplete(
    {
        minLength: 1,
        source: function( request, response ) 
        {
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(items, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() 
        {
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) 
        {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you call local txt file in javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you have a string, try to parse the response:

```
$.get('Keywords.txt').then(function(keywords){
    items = JSON.parse(keywords);
});
```

Comment: Hi Marius, i tried to implement this but i guess i am doing something wrong in implementation. can you please guide me how & where to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Balvinder, i created a Plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/sGVTAV6zHrISfRExoMjA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Marius. I did placed your suggestion at right place first time but didn't mentioned items as array so it was not working. anyways, now it's working fine. But there is one thing which is bothering me. "is there any way that instead of loading full list of keywords at once, when user provides any input, it just fetch related suggestions from text file?"